# How to setup LUIS AI required entities / items for an action?

Tags: nlp, artificial-intelligence, chatbot, azure-language-understanding

I am using LUIS for a chat bot. 
I created an action. I require certain entities to be present and would like to prompt the user to enter the entities if they're missing from the action.

How do I do this?

All the tutorials online show setting it up from the bot builder web UI but Microsoft has since deprecated setting up prompts from LUIS's web UI.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying upon Microsoft to do this, I prefer to only use LUIS for intent analysis and entity extraction.

You can store all the entities required to perform an operation(mapped to an intent) in some DB or just cache in a Map. Once you have Intent and entities corresponding to user input, you can match whether it contains all the entities or not. If not, just club all the missing entities and prompt user for remaining entities.

This might add some coding effort, but reduces a lot of dependency from cloud based applications. You also won't need to make any change if there is any change in endpoint URLs from LUIS or any of the cloud providers.

Comment: How do you process the users input when prompted to ask for the entities? Do you have a separate action for when the user enters any type of missing input? I.e. if I ask "What country do you want to visit?" and they reply "I'd like to visit Morocco".

Comment: In the code handling the intent, check the Entites of your result and perform actions depending on what you got in the Entities

Comment: @tt_Gantz you need to explicitly handle this in your code. There can be multiple ways for this based on your requirement. One can be to consider last intent if you don't find any new intent and add new entities to the entities that you received in previous chat from user.

Comment: @user1728310 so let LUIS figure out what entities are being sent through from the user? If luis gets the intent wrong, but the entities are right, then just map the entities sent through to the ones missing from the last intent